# Vue: @mouseover.stop still bubbling

Tags: vue.js

I need to trigger a mouseover in Vue, but only on an element and its children, but not its parent. According to documentation this should work with the `.stop` modifier, but for some reason it still bubbles. `.self` wont work on child elements.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

The code is simple:

```
<div v-for="(element) in elements" :key="element.id" :class="element.states"
    @mouseover.stop="element.states.hover = true"
    @mouseleave.stop="element.states.hover = false"></div>
```

Or on a component:

```
<my-component v-for="(element) in elements" :key="element.id" :class="element.states"
    @mouseover.native.stop="element.states.hover = true"
    @mouseleave.native.stop="element.states.hover = false"></my-component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some extensive testing and try&error I found the reason why it was not working:
Due to the DOM nesting the `mouseleave` event is not fired, when hovering over a child. Also thanks @Shoejep for the test with logging, where you can see this behaviour.

To fix it, I had to use `mouseout` event on the children which gets fired on the parent when entering a child.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a simple snippet to show how you can use @mouseover and @mouseleave with the stop event modifier and it seems to work, i.e. you only see BodyOver and BodyLeave in the console when entering and leaving the outer element.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => {
    return {
      parents: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    over(ev) {
      console.log(`Over ${ev.target.classList[0]}`);
    },
    leave(ev) {
      console.log(`Leave ${ev.target.classList[0]}`);
    },
    bodyOver(ev) {
      console.log(`Body Over ${ev.target.classList[0]}`);
    },
    bodyLeave(ev) {
      console.log(`Body Leave ${ev.target.classList[0]}`);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.body {
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.parent {
  padding: 20px;
  background: green;
}

.child {
  padding: 20px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="body" @mouseover="bodyOver" @mouseleave="bodyLeave">
    Body
    <div class="parent" @mouseover.stop="over" @mouseleave.stop="leave" v-for="parent in parents">
      Parent
      <div class="child">
        Child
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```